# how to make the process of putting the output of a command in a variable a background process

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

My actual goal is to show "Loading..." while a different command is taking time to output. So:

```
#When running this, it takes about 3 seconds before it outputs something into the terminal.
deluge-console status

#I want to show "Loading..." in those 3 seconds.
#This was my plan:
unset output
output=$(deluge-console status) &
until [[ -n "$output" ]]
do
    echo "Loading..."
    sleep 1s
done
echo "$output"
```

Doing `$(..) &` shows Loading... endlessly. Doing $(... &) doesn't show Loading... and just waits for the command to output and after that echo's $output.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

What you did here was starting `deluge-console status` in a sub-shell and then putting the assignment to the `output` variable in the background with the `&` at the end of that line.

That is certainly not what you wanted: It waits until the `deluge-console status` command is finished (because that's what `$(...)` does) which might take a few seconds, then it does the one thing that is quick anyway (assigning the output of that command to the variable) in the background.

Comment: I understand it. It sounds very logical. So that would mean that I'm searching for "Putting the complete setting-a-value-for-the-variable in the background". How can I do that then?

Comment: You don't. That's not how shell scripts work. Simply start your notification independently of the output of that other command that takes a long time. You can give it a command line parameter indicating what you are about to start, but don't rely on the longer-lasting command's output. The whole point of a splash-screen like output is to be quick and not wait for anything that can take a while.

Comment: @HuHa better add that you cannot, and why you cannot to the actual answer.